# Simple Difference Equation Question

Tags: signal-processing, signal-theory

Consider the linear constant coefficient difference equation

$$
  y[n] - \frac{3}{4}y[n-1] + \frac{1}{8}y[n-2] = 2x[n-1]
$$

Determine \$y[n]\$ for \$n \ge 0\$ when \$x[n] = \delta[n]\$ and \$y[n] = 0, n < 0\$.

The answer is

$$
  y[n] = 8[(1/2)^n - (1/4)^n]u[n]
$$

My question is how do they get that? I can manually calculate the first few values of \$y[n]\$:

\begin{align*}
  y[0] &= 0 \\
  y[1] &= 2 \\
  y[2] &= 3/2 \\
  y[3] &= 7/8 \\
  y[4] &= 15/32 \\
  y[5] &= 31/128 \\
\end{align*}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider definition of H(z), it is the output of a LTI system when input is **δ[n]**.

So,in order to determine y[n] at x[n]=δ[n], we have to determine only h[n].

First of all, take Z-transform of the system transfer function.

[image]

[image]

Re-arranging terms,

[image]

Now, we can solve this equation using partial fraction

[image]

Taking inverse Z-Transform:

[image]

- In the 3rd equation, **H(z)=Y(z)/X(z)**

Comment: Thank you so much!!! That is actually fairly simple when you explained it.